# Applying AND condition on same column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table structure in this format:

```
# id  attributeId   projectId
'28'    '20'          '87' 
'29'    '21'          '87' 
'30'    '22'          '570' 
'31'    '20'          '570' 
'32'    '30'          '570'
```

I want to pass attribute IDs as parameter and get the projectId which has all attributes assigned to it.

For ex : if I pass 20,30 attribute Ids, i should only get 570 project ID and not 87, as 30 is not assigned to 87.

```
SELECT * FROM fm05__project_attributes where attributeId in (20,30);
```

The above query gives me, the below result which is not correct.

```
id  attributeId   projectId
28    20              87    
31    20              570   
32    30              570
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT projectId
FROM  fm05__project_attributes
WHERE attributeId IN (20,30)
GROUP BY projectId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: (Or, possibly, (DISTINCT attributeid) )

Comment: There could be many attribute IDs passed as parameters and we do not know the count of either the number of attribute Ids or the project Ids

Comment: @danish it would almost inconceivable that this information would be 'unknown'

Comment: attributeIds could be 20,21,24,30, in this case the user would select 4 attribute Ids, we want to fetch all the project Ids to which all these attributes are assigned.

Comment: @Danish What's the issue? You can easily count how many items you are passing and put a variable in the `HAVING COUNT(*)` clause.